# MX Master 3 bluetooth mouse not recognized by Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, 23.10

Just installed Ubuntu 23.10 on my Lenovo laptop but it cannot detect my MX Master 3 mouse. I am trying to pair it manually but no success. Any idea?

```
sonata@DeepBlue:~$ sudo hcitool scan
[sudo] password for sonata: 
 Scanning ...
sonata@DeepBlue:~$


sonata@DeepBlue:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller E0:0A:F6:A1:C9:C2 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]#
```

==========================================

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller E0:0A:F6:A1:C9:C2 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A MX Master 3
[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A RSSI: 0xffffffde (-34)
[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A Trusted: yes
[bluetooth]# connect EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A
Attempting to connect to EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A
[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A Connected: yes
Connection successful
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_EB_32_F0_8C_2B_4A/service000a
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Generic Attribute Profile

[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A WakeAllowed: yes
[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device EB:32:F0:8C:2B:4A Connected: no
```

Comment: Potentially stupid question, but you're sure you set the mouse in pairing mode?

Comment: If the mouse was detected by Ubuntu I could pair it. My laptop is dual boot Windows 11 + Ubuntu and the mouse works on Windows 11 like a charm.

Comment: Yes, but the mouse is not in pairing mode by default. You have to hold the channel selection button (on the mouse) in until the light starts blinking rapidly.

Comment: Thanks bro I think I am very close to the solution .In my case channel selection button is on the bottom of the mouse. It was in the position 1 and I changed it to 2 and the light started blinking rapidly, MX master appeared in the bluman  window on desktop I checked the green checkmark and trusted it. There is a notification on my display saying mouse connected but when I move the mouse my mouse pointer does not move. The light on the bottom remains blinking rapidly.

Comment: I edited the body

Comment: I disconnected and connected the mouse and problem solved it works now.